# Android VideoView playing local file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-videoview

I am trying to play a local mp4 video file using VideoView in Xamarin Android project. The video works on debug mode, but crashes on release mode.

This is what I have done.

I have created a "Raw" folder inside the resources folder and have placed the video file in it.I have ensured that the Build property is set to "Android resources", and I have also tried with and without checking "Copy to output directory" option too.

I have tried different sizes of video files: 5MB, 1.2MB and 740KB (all individually)

```
  var videoView = FindViewById<VideoView> (Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);
var mediControls = new MediaController (this);
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://" + PackageName + "/"+Resource.Raw.testvideo);
videoView.SetVideoURI(uri);
videoView.SetMediaController (mediControls);
videoView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
videoView.Start ();
```

Following is the exception that is thrown

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.RuntimeException' was thrown.
[MonoDroid] at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x00028>
[MonoDroid] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) <0x000e7>
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) <0x001d3>
[MonoDroid] at Talkative_Parents.EulaActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle)  <0x00033>
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005b>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.a9697909-b7c3-4854-9da3-0ca8569ec268 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] java.lang.NullPointerException
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:392)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
[MonoDroid]     at md58b22d079704faa69564ee4d4fd03e330.EulaActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at md58b22d079704faa69564ee4d4fd03e330.EulaActivity.onCreate(EulaActivity.java:30)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
[MonoDroid]     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[Xamarin.Insights] Warning: Could not write journal: Internal error Flush
[Xamarin.Insights] {"InnerException": null,"HelpLink": null,"HResult": -2146233087,"Message": "Internal error Flush","Source": "System","StackTrace": "  at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamNative.CheckResult (Int32 result, System.String where) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamNative.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 \n  at Xamarin.InsightsCore.IOWriter.WriteDiskImage (System.String fileName, System.String stringToWrite) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 ","TargetSite": "CheckResult","Data": {},"getType": "System.IO.IOException"}
[Xamarin.Insights] Warning: Unhandled exception: System.IO.IOException: Internal error Flush
[Xamarin.Insights]   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamNative.CheckResult (Int32 result, System.String where) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Xamarin.Insights]   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamNative.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Xamarin.Insights]   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Xamarin.Insights]   at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Xamarin.Insights]   at Xamarin.InsightsCore.IOWriter.WriteDiskImage (System.String fileName, System.String stringToWrite) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Xamarin.Insights] Warning: Unhandled exception: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.RuntimeException' was thrown.
[Xamarin.Insights] at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x00028>
[Xamarin.Insights] at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) <0x000e7>
[Xamarin.Insights] at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) <0x001d3>
[Xamarin.Insights] at Talkative_Parents.EulaActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x00033>
[Xamarin.Insights] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005b>
[Xamarin.Insights] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.a9697909-b7c3-4854-9da3-0ca8569ec268 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00043>
[Xamarin.Insights] 
[Xamarin.Insights]   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
[Xamarin.Insights] java.lang.NullPointerException
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:392)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at md58b22d079704faa69564ee4d4fd03e330.EulaActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at md58b22d079704faa69564ee4d4fd03e330.EulaActivity.onCreate(EulaActivity.java:30)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
[Xamarin.Insights]  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check if the linker is enabled for the release build, if so, disable it and test again. It may be stripping out API methods.

Comment: @matthewrobbinsdev : I have just tried disabling the linker and still the issue persists.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately that rules out the easy fix :/

Comment: I'll put together a test app and see if I can reproduce.

Comment: Similar settings work for me in both release and debug and on a device/emulator. There must be another factor. What Android version is this being deployed to?

Comment: @matthewrobbinsdev : I have tried on android 5.1.0(lolipop) and and 4.4.2 (kitkat). Did you use native android or xamarin android? I am using Xamarin.Android

Comment: I used Xamarin.Android. My test device is 5.1.1 and the emulator is KitKat.

Comment: @matthewrobbinsdev : You are right. I just tested in a new project and it works fine. Do u have any idea about what else can be effecting it. Does the resource folder have a size limit?

Comment: I don't know if it does honestly but I can't imagine approx 20mb worth of files would cause the error. I'd dig into the `AppCompat` error at the top of the stack trace. It might be the cause.